# Java Program - Control Dependence Graph

Tags: java

Are there any good tools APIs out there for generating a system dependence graph from java source code? I'm not interested in visual generators. I would like to toy around with a tool that generates a system dependence graph into memory that can then be acted upon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean with system dependence graph? How classes in your own code depend on each other, or how your system depends on libraries (jars) from other providers (and they depend on other libs), or on the level of architectural layers (how your webserver depends on the database etc)?

For the first, look at [PMD](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/) and other code analyzers, for jars I've seen maven and other dependency management tools come up with interesting data, but for architectural layers I can only advise drawing them up yourselves...

Comment: I just took at it there but I can't see how it will help me.